# Javascript global resetting

Tags: javascript

I am somewhat new to Javascript have read some into it and got the following problem: I created a global var, i'm setting it in a function and i'm trying to call it in another function but it comes out as undefined.
I've googled around and it seems it's called Javascript Hoisting Decleration. But i can't find the solution on this. This is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var value;
function getComboBox() {
    var value = document.getElementById('vereniging').value;
    console.log(value);
}
function isChanged() {
    console.log(value);
    var chboxs = document.getElementById('checkbox');
    var show = document.getElementById('hidden');
    if(chboxs.checked && value=='BNI') {
    show2.style.display= 'block';
    show.style.display='none';
    }
    if(chboxs.checked && value=='WTC') {    
    show2.style.display='none';
    show.style.display='block';
    }
} </script>
```

it sets correctly with the first function.

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: This is an issue with [scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx), using `var value =...` inside the function is creating a different variable with a local scope instead of using the globally scoped one.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var value = document.getElementById('vereniging').value;
> ```

You are declaring a new variable instead of writing into global one.

If you want to use global, remove `var`.